# Email Router Configuration Manager (Entity with a name = officedocument was not found in the metadata cache)

Tags: dynamics-crm

the email router configuration manager was unable to retrieve user and queue information from the microsoft dynamics crm server . this may indicate that the microsoft dynamics crm server is busy . verify that url * is correct . additionally this problem can occur if specified access credentials are insufficient . to try again click load data the entity with a name = officedocument was not found in the metadata cache

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"officedocument" entity only available in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online not in on-premise

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328086.aspx

best regard
Mani

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about entity name? I mean, when you create a custom entity it have a prefix, by default "new_".

For instance, when you create a new Entity, depending on the prefix of your organization, it will be like: "stck_officedocument" or "new_officedocument" etc.

Check it and then change for the correct name.

Comment: yes i'm sure ! it's not about custom entity ! this error about email router